# Decode Barcode Image in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, image, using, barcode, decode

I am working on decoding barcode image in ASP.NEt using C#.
In this i amtaking reference from the [website](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/BarcodeImaging3.aspx).
In this,i dont understand what is (int start) and (int end) parameters in the function
Readbarcode.
Pls tell how to find int start and int end parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try Zxing.net  Its helps to convert barcode bitmap images to barcodetext try installing using Nuget Package or try this link    
https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net

or try Neudynamic barcode sdk

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is the y-coordinate start and stop of the scan of the image.

E.g.
If you provide 10 and 20, it will try to find barcodes in the image in the area from Y-coordinate 10 to 20 from left to right.

[image: illustration]